# Altair mark_image not working due to Javascript error

Tags: python, altair

I'm running the following code (copied exactly from the official documentation [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html#image-mark)) to create a scatterplot with image markers.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
      {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png"},
      {"x": 1.5, "y": 1.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png"},
      {"x": 2.5, "y": 2.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/7zip.png"}
])

alt.Chart(source).mark_image(
    width=50,
    height=50
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    url='img'
)
```

It's returning this error message:

> Javascript Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n[e.type][t]')
>
> This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the JavaScript console for the full traceback.

What does that error message mean? Am I missing some required library to display images?

Comment: Could you provide information about how you are running the code? Jupyterlab? If so, which browser? You might want to try in a private/incognito windows in case you have addons interfering with JS. Which version of Altair?

Comment: I tried to run it in jupyterlab environment. It is displayed normally. The version used is: altair:4.1.0. The relevant modules are listed below, are they up to date? `jinja2, jsonschema, entrypoints, numpy, pandas, toolz`

Answer (score 0):

Well... I made no changes and it worked when I ran the same code today.

Thanks for the suggestions @joelostblom and @r-beginners. I was running the code in a Jupyter notebook in the Safari browser. Here are the versions of my relevant modules:

- altair 4.1.0
- jinja2 2.11.2
- jsonschema 3.2.0
- entrypoints 0.3
- numpy 1.19.5
- pandas 1.1.5
- tools 0.11.1
- jupyter-notebook 6.1.4